# How can we use dependencies function in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the code below the problem is that this dependency is never called. is there any way to call it?

```
class NewBrandWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  void dependencies() {

    Get.create<ShoppingController>(() => ShoppingController());
    print("1");
          }
}
```

Comment: `dependencies` is not a method you can overwrite. It does not exist.

Comment: What do you expect the function to be used for?

Comment: @stanm I want it to be called as when the widget gets build

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the `build` method, as @Alexander Dischberg pointed out in his answer. Or are you looking for a method that is called *before/after* the widget has been built (rather than *during*)?

Answer (score 0):

`@override` means you are overriding the base class method. StatelessWidget doesn't have any function called `dependencies` and it only have who method which are the `build` method which is the only method you use in a statelesswidget and `createElement` method which unlikely to be used in normal usage. Do more research on how `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` works.

Comment: so if I change stateless to stateful it would be fine?

Comment: @Ardeshirojan No it will not. watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqCMFXEmf3w or  see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html for more info